# PNP TIP126 transistor hot to touch while in use

Tags: transistors, pnp, darlington

I have a 7-segment mechanical 'vane' display andbgot it working using a circuit originally suggested to me here. The diagram below is a slightly modified version.

Each vane draws around 0.2A of current when switched on. Therefore if all segments are set at once, a total of 1.44A is drawn.

The circuit works.

The PNP Darlington transistor, [TIP126](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip120-d.pdf) (Q1,) has a maximum continuous collector current of 5A .

Clearly I only need to operate the vanes briefly. However, while testing I left the vanes on for a while (around 30 seconds) and the transistor was getting quite hot to the touch.

Is this normal? I don't think it's an issue given how briefly the vanes have to operate but I wanted to check I wasn't going to do any long-term damage to the transistor, even though the vanes only operate briefly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Any Darlington transistor when turned-on or activated will, by the very nature of the transistor configuration inside the device, drop about 0.7 volts to 1.2 volts between collector and emitter for even quite meagre collector currents. The [TIP126 data sheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip120-d.pdf) indicates 2 volts when 3 amps flow: -

[image]

So, this means that they are not very power efficient because, power = volts x amps and, if the current is 1.44 amps and the voltage is around 1 volt, then the power dissipated will be 1.44 watts and will significantly warm a transistor that does not have a heatsink even if it is a TO-220 type.

> *Is this normal?*

I would say it is to be expected given what you have said. As to whether it is normal depends on what temperature the device rises to.

Comment: I'd guess closer to 2 watts. And is it about 62 watts per K to ambient, and 2 watts per K to the case. So yeah. Very hot.

Comment: @jonk 62 degC per watt I think you meant and 2 degC per watt for junction to case.

Comment: 62 per watt per K (or C) junction to ambient. On datasheet I looked at. 2 watt junction to case.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess. You have not put a heat sink on your TIP, right? Andy aka's answer holds the key to the other half of the problem. The TIP can dissipate the power, but it needs help to do it without getting hot.

The standard approach is to bolt the TIP to a piece of metal, aluminum for cost, copper for performance, with a thermal pad or (very thin!) layer of silicone grease with an additive in between. For smallish loads, you can use a smallish heat sink and let natural convection cool it. For larger dissipations, you need forced air or liquid cooling.